# Prove that $\|u_x\|_2=\|\operatorname{curl}u\|_2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Using the facts: $\operatorname{div}u=0$ and $u\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$

I need to proof, that:
$\|u_x\|_2=\|\operatorname{curl}u\|_2$,
where $||u||_p=(\int |u|^p dx )^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

I used the last formula and wrote
$\|\operatorname{curl}u\|_2=(\int |\operatorname{curl}u|^2 \,  dx )^{\frac{1}{2}}$,

$$|\operatorname{curl}u|^2=(\operatorname{curl}u)_x^2+(\operatorname{curl}u)_y^2+(\operatorname{curl}u)_z^2,$$

then I used that $\operatorname{curl}$ can be presented as determinant and wrote the last formula in an explicit form in terms of function $u$.

I also used that $\displaystyle|u_x|^2=\sum_{i,k=1}^3 \left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x^k}\right)^2$.

Than I put all relations in $\|u_x\|_2=\|\operatorname{curl}u\|_2$, but I got on the both sides items that are not reduced.

Comment: You should probably ask this @ Mathematics.SE

Comment: I don't understand your notation. If $u$ is a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then usually $u_x$ denotes the $x$-component in the cartesian system. However, you say $$|u_x|^2 = \sum_{i,k=1}^3 \left( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x^k} \right)^2.$$

Comment: There $x$ means $\mathbf{x}$: $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, so my definition of $|\mathbf{u}_x|$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation*}
\|\mathbf{u}_x\|_2=\|\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u}\|_2,
\end{equation*}
if $\operatorname{div} \mathbf{u}=0$ and $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})\to0$ while $|\mathbf{x}|\to\infty$.

Let's prove it:
\begin{equation*}
\|\mathbf{u}_x\|_2=\left(\int\sum\limits_{i=1,k}^3 \left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x^k}\right)^2 dx\right)^{1/2}=
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\left(\int\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right)^2+\right.
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\left.+\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}\right)^2 ~dx\right)^{1/2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\|\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u}\|_2=\left(\int|\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u}|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
|\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u}|^2=(\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u})_{x_1}^2+(\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u})_{x_2}^2+(\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u})_{x_3}^2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u}=\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\ 
\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} \\ 
u_1 & u_2 & u_3  \notag
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
|\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u}|^2=\left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}-\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}-\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}\right)^2=
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}\right)^2-
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-2\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}-2\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}-2\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}
\end{equation*}

You see that some terms in left side and in the right side of identity are equal. Now we need to prove that other are same too:

On the first side
\begin{equation*}
\int\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}d^3x=u_2\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}-\int u_2\frac{\partial^2 u_3}{\partial x_2\partial x_3}dx=
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\langle\mathbf{u}\to 0~\mbox{при}~\mathbf{x}\to\infty\rangle=-\int u_2\frac{\partial^2 u_3}{\partial x_2\partial x_3}dx
\end{equation*}
on the other
\begin{equation*}
\int\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}d^3x=\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}u_3-\int \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x_3\partial x_2} u_3dx=
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\langle\mathbf{u}\to 0~\mbox{при}~\mathbf{x}\to\infty\rangle=-\int \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x_3\partial x_2} u_3dx
\end{equation*}
Sum the two expressions
\begin{equation*}
-2\int\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}d^3x=\int (u_2\frac{\partial^2 u_3}{\partial x_2\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x_3\partial x_2} u_3)dx
\end{equation*}

For two others similarly. Then:
\begin{equation*}
-2\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_2}-2\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}-2\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}=
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
=\int \left(u_2\frac{\partial^2 u_3}{\partial x_2\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x_3\partial x_2} u_3+u_3\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_3\partial x_1}+\right.
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\left.+\frac{\partial^2 u_3}{\partial x_1\partial x_3} u_1+u_1\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_2\partial x_1} u_2\right)dx
\end{equation*}

Let's use that $\operatorname{div} \mathbf{u}=0$:
\begin{equation*}
u_2\left[\frac{\partial^2 u_3}{\partial x_2\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}\right]=u_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left[\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\right]=-u_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
u_3\left[\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x_3\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_3\partial x_1}\right]=-u_3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
u_1\left[\frac{\partial^2 u_3}{\partial x_1\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}\right]=-u_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}
\end{equation*}

Than show that
\begin{equation*}
-\int \left( u_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}+u_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}+u_3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right)dx
\end{equation*}
are equivalent to the remaining terms on the left side.
\begin{equation*}
\int\left(\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}\right)^2\right)dx
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\int\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\right)^2dx=\int\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}dx=\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}u_1-\int u_1\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_1 \partial x_1}dx=
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=-\int u_1\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x_1 \partial x_1}dx
\end{equation*}
The first term is equal to the first on the another side. We perform similarly for the rest. Therefore, for solenoidal fields true identity:
\begin{equation*}
\|\mathbf{u}_x\|_2=\|\operatorname{rot} \mathbf{u}\|_2
\end{equation*}